# How to check what storage phase is an index in (hot, worm...) - Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-ilm

I added a life cycle policy and want to ensure it takes effect and the indices are in the 'warm' phase as they should be.

I couldn't find what is the command to view that information.
Is it possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Explain Lifecycle API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-explain-lifecycle.html) for checking current phase of Index.

```
GET my-index-000001/_ilm/explain
```

```json
{
  "indices": {
    "my-index-000001": {
      "index": "my-index-000001",
      "index_creation_date_millis": 1538475653281,  
      "time_since_index_creation": "15s",           
      "managed": true,                              
      "policy": "my_policy",                        
      "lifecycle_date_millis": 1538475653281,       
      "age": "15s",                                 
      "phase": "new",  <--- this is indicating phase of index. 
      "phase_time_millis": 1538475653317,           
      "action": "complete"
      "action_time_millis": 1538475653317,          
      "step": "complete",
      "step_time_millis": 1538475653317             
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So can I filter it?

In Kibana Index Management, I can filter "ilm.phase:(warm)" from the lifecycle phase section.

Can we use a similar filter here?

Unfortunately, I did not see such an option in the documentation.